# How to create PHP code for this JSON

Tags: php, json

**Simple way to create PHP part for this JSON code**

```
    {
        "contacts": [
            {
                    "id": "c200",
                    "name": "Ravi Tamada",
                    "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
                    "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                    "gender" : "male",
                    "phone": {
                        "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                        "home": "00 000000",
                        "office": "00 000000"
                    }
            },
            {
                    "id": "c201",
                    "name": "Johnny Depp",
                    "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
                    "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                    "gender" : "male",
                    "phone": {
                        "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                        "home": "00 000000",
                        "office": "00 000000"
                    }
            },

    ]
}
```

I create simple JSON response But have problem with multi-objects and arrays.

Comment: All this info is stored inside MYSQL database.

Answer (score 1):

You can create array like:

```
$a = array("contacts" => array(
     array(
            "id" => "c200",
            "name" => "Ravi Tamada",
            "email" => "ravi@gmail.com",
            "address" => "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender"  => "male",
            "phone" => array(
                "mobile" => "+91 0000000000",
                "home" => "00 000000",
                "office" => "00 000000"
            )
        ),
       array(
            "id" => "c201",
            "name" => "Johnny Depp",
            "email" => "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
            "address" => "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender"  => "male",
            "phone" => array(
                "mobile" => "+91 0000000000",
                "home" => "00 000000",
                "office" => "00 000000"
            )
        ),
    )
);

echo json_encode($a);
```

Result:

```
{"contacts":[{"id":"c200","name":"Ravi Tamada","email":"ravi@gmail.com","address":"xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country","gender":"male","phone":{"mobile":"+91 0000000000","home":"00 000000","office":"00 000000"}},{"id":"c201","name":"Johnny Depp","email":"johnny_depp@gmail.com","address":"xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country","gender":"male","phone":{"mobile":"+91 0000000000","home":"00 000000","office":"00 000000"}}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually easy to do yourself

Take your existing JSON string and just put it through `json_decode`. This will create the equivalent PHP data structure for you.

```
$json = "...";
$data = json_decode($json);
var_dump($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo json_encode([
    "contacts" => [
        [
            "id" => "c200",
            "name" => "Ravi Tamada",
            "email" => "ravi@gmail.com",
            "address" => "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender"  => "male",
            "phone" => [
                "mobile" => "+91 0000000000",
                "home" => "00 000000",
                "office" => "00 000000"
            ]
        ],
        [
            "id" => "c201",
            "name" => "Johnny Depp",
            "email" => "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
            "address" => "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender"  => "male",
            "phone" => [
                "mobile" => "+91 0000000000",
                "home" => "00 000000",
                "office" => "00 000000"
            ]
        ],

    ]
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a PHP code that generates the structure from that (or another) json you should combine the use of [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php) + [var_export](http://php.net/manual/es/function.var-export.php).

```
$json = '... your json code ...';
$phpcode = var_export(json_decode($json_string));
```

It will create the structure for your code, in your particular case:

```
stdClass::__set_state(array(
   'contacts' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'id' => 'c200',
       'name' => 'Ravi Tamada',
       'email' => 'ravi@gmail.com',
       'address' => 'xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country',
       'gender' => 'male',
       'phone' => 
      stdClass::__set_state(array(
         'mobile' => '+91 0000000000',
         'home' => '00 000000',
         'office' => '00 000000',
      )),
    )),
    1 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'id' => 'c201',
       'name' => 'Johnny Depp',
       'email' => 'johnny_depp@gmail.com',
       'address' => 'xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country',
       'gender' => 'male',
       'phone' => 
      stdClass::__set_state(array(
         'mobile' => '+91 0000000000',
         'home' => '00 000000',
         'office' => '00 000000',
      )),
    )),
  ),
));
```

Still you won't be able to create the object because stdClass doesn't have the method __set_state, you can read more about it here: http://blog.thoughtlabs.com/blog/2008/02/02/phps-mystical-__set_state-method

*Note: There is an extra "," after the second element of conctacts that you should remove.*